# How to pass additional arguments to sort function

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a 2D array and I'm using a custom sort function to sort it by column. My code structure is similar to this:

```
function sortBy(array, primaryCol, secondaryCol) {
    function compareNumber(a, b) {
        if (a[primaryCol] == b[primaryCol]) {
            return a[secondaryCol] - b[secondaryCol] ? -1 : 1;
        }
        return a[primaryCol] - b[primaryCol];
    }
    array.sort(compareNumber);
}
sortBy(colors, 3, 0);
```

Inside the `compareNumber` function, I'm accessing `primaryCol` and `secondaryCol` parameters of the `sortBy` function. What I want to do is move `compareNumber` function outside of `sortBy`. In that case, the code won't work, because `compareNumber` can't access `primaryCol` and `secondaryCol`. Also passing `primaryCol` and `secondaryCol` to `compareNumber` function doesn't do any good, because I guess it takes only two arguments.

```
function compareNumber(a, b, primaryCol, secondaryCol) {
    if (a[primaryCol] == b[primaryCol]) {
        return a[secondaryCol] < b[secondaryCol] ? -1 : 1;
    }
    return a[primaryCol] - b[primaryCol];
}
function sortBy(array, primaryCol, secondaryCol) {
    array.sort(compareNumber, primaryCol, secondaryCol);
}
sortBy(colors, 3, 0);
```

So, is there any way to make this work, pass additional arguments to sort function other than `a` and `b`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `bind` to pass it parameters:

```
function compareNumber(a, b) {
    if (a[this[0]] == b[this[0]]) {
        return a[this[0]] < b[this[1]] ? -1 : 1;
    }
    return a[this[0]] - b[this[0]];
}
function sortBy(array, primaryCol, secondaryCol) {
    array.sort(compareNumber.bind([primaryCol, secondaryCol]));
}
sortBy(colors, 3, 0);
```

The bound argument now becomes assigned to the `this` value, so your pirmaryCol is in `this[0]` and your secondary is in `this[1]`.

Comment: This seems to be more applicable to my problem, because the number of the columns isn't going to be fixed. It'll vary. And assigning an array to `this` seems easier. Otherwise I'll have to pass each column manually.

Answer (score 1):

Add the extra params then wrap or [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the comparator to pass in these arguments with every invocation

```
function compareNumber(primaryCol, secondaryCol, a, b) {
    if (a[primaryCol] == b[primaryCol]) {
        return a[secondaryCol] - b[secondaryCol] ? -1 : 1;
    }
    return a[primaryCol] - b[primaryCol];
}

function sortBy(array, primaryCol, secondaryCol) {
    array.sort(compareNumber.bind(null, primaryCol, secondaryCol));
}
sortBy(colors, 3, 0);
```

Or

```
// ...
    array.sort(function (a, b) {return compareNumber(primaryCol, secondaryCol, a, b);});
// ...
```

If your comparator uses `this` then I'd recommend `.bind` as there is less overhead in the one-off than needing to `.call` or `.apply` each time.